# Not All Site Collections show up in the results - Sharepoint 2013 Search through CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am working on a C# code that retrieves all site collection paths from a On-Premise Sharepoint 2013 server. I have the following Site Collections on the server:

/serverurl/
/serverurl/my
/serverurl/my/personal/site1
/serverurl/my/personal/site2
/serverurl/sites/TestSite
/serverurl/custompath/site3

when I run my code , I only get the following site collections:
/serverurl/
/serverurl/my
/serverurl/my/personal/site1
/serverurl/my/personal/site2
I was wondering why my search does not return all the site collections?
here is my code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
var cred = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
context.Credentials = cred;
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(context);
query.QueryText = "contentclass:STS_Site";
SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor(context);
query.TrimDuplicates = true;
var resultTable = executor.ExecuteQuery(query);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var row in resultTable.Value[0].ResultRows)
{
   string siteName = row["siteName"] as string;
   Console.WriteLine("Site Name: {0}", siteName);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about your search index ? In the central admin, you can check in the Search Service Application the Crawl History and see if there are some items from your missing collection site.

Comment: The missing Site Collections do exist in search index. if Iuse the query:"path:serverurl/sites/TestSite", I get the missing site collection, but "contentclass:STS_Site" query is supposed to return all site collections which does not. I think it's somehow related to serach permisions, but I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem today. I found two solutions.

Regardless if your on-prem or on Office365 we can use Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant dll.  You can use this to get all the Site Collections.  You do need your admins to run some power shell if your on-prem.  Vesa was nice enough to write a blog about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2014/06/09/provisioning-site-collections-using-sp-app-model-in-on-premises-with-just-csom/)

Once you get that done, you can do something like the following (Note:I have not tested this method with a non Admin account) (solution taken from [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137739/i-want-to-get-list-of-all-site-collection-available-on-sharepoint-server-2013-us)) Sadly this one will not work for me as I want security trimming and this will code must be ran by a user with tenant read permissions which our users would not normal have.

```
var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerable spp = tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, true);
clientContext.Load(spp);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(SiteProperties sp in spp)
{
    // you'll get your site collections here
}
```

I ended up doing this which gets back to using search, I still have a problem, we have well over 500 sites/webs so I'm working with our admins to see if we can increase the max rows search can return. However, **the true secret here is `TrimDuplicates` being set to false**, I don't know why SP thinks the results are dups, but it obviously does, so set it to false and you should see all your sits.

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(ctx);
query.QueryText = "contentclass:\"STS_Site\"";
query.RowLimit = 500;//max row limit is 500 for KeywordQuery
query.EnableStemming = true;
query.TrimDuplicates = false;
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(query);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var data = results.Value.SelectMany(rs => rs.ResultRows.Select(r => r["Path"])).ToList();
```

Hope one of the two will work for you.